# jQuery: Can I automatically apply a plug-in to a dynamically added element?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm in the process of converting my web app to a fully AJAX architecture.

I have my master page that is initially loaded and a div container that is loaded with dynamic content.

I created a few jQuery plugins that I apply to certain elements in order to extend their functionality. I'd normally call the functions as follows during each page load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Enable fancy AJAX search
    $(".entity-search-table").EntitySearch();

});
```

This would find the appropriate div(s) and call the plugin to enable the necessary functionality.

In an AJAX environment I can't just apply the plugin during the page load since elements will be added and removed dynamically.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Enable fancy AJAX search
    $(".entity-search-table").live("load", function () {
        $(this).EntitySearch();
    });

});
```

**Question:** Is there any way that I can trigger an event when a `<div>` or other element that matches a selector is added to the DOM?

It seems incredibly wasteful to activate the plug-in every time an AJAX request completes. The plug-in only needs to be applied to the element once when it is first added to the DOM.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may already have your architecture underway, but in case you don't I'll throw in a plug for my [AJAXFetch jQuery plug-in](http://phrogz.net/JS/AJAXFetch/) that uses markup to allow you to perform a variety of AJAX-style swaps on your page automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - take a look at [liveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery). Example:

```
$('.entity-search-table').livequery(function(){ 
    $(this).EntitySearch(); 
});
```

Comment: This binds to the load event of each, you need *only* `$(this).EntitySearch();` as the body of the handler :)

Comment: @Nick - that's what I get for creating an example from something I've never used :S

Comment: That looks like exactly what I had imagined. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> It seems incredibly wasteful to activate the plug-in every time an AJAX request completes. The plug-in only needs to be applied to the element once when it is first added to the DOM.

You can get the best of both worlds here, for example:

```
$("#something").load("url", function() {
  $(".entity-search-table", this).EntitySearch();
});
```

This way it's only applying the plugin to the `.entity-search-table` elements you *just* loaded, since we specified a context to [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to limit it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the live binding in your plugin code directly

```
jQuery.fn.EntitySearch = function() {
   this.live(..., function(){ your plugin code });
   return this;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a link to the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and/or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) methods for jQuery would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The [DOM 2 MutationEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) is what you really want, but unfortunately it isn't supported by IE. You'll need to either use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)/ [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) binding in the plug-in, or (as I did when I had to work around this) use callbacks from your AJAX loaders indicating the scope of what has changed.