# Trouble with Jquery change method

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery's `change()` method in my code.

```
 $("select,input,textarea").change(function ()
    {
        needToConfirm = true;
        alert("needToConfirm :" + needToConfirm); 
    })
```

It's working fine with all `select`, `input` as well as `textarea` element except for following `textarea` element

```
<textarea name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" class="mceEditor" rows="4" cols="125">${myForm.someAttribute }</textarea>
```

I observed that other `textarea` don't have any dynamic value while this `myTextArea` have `${myForm.someAttribute}` value. This seems to be the cause but I am not able to figure out the exact reason.

Its working fine with following `textarea` element

```
<textarea path="studySummary" cssClass="fieldValue mediumFontSize" rows="4" cols="95" tabindex="67"/>
```

**EDIT:**
Hello All,
All things are working fine but I came across a new issue. I have some HTML elements like `select`,`input` etc which get added dynamically through javascript. How can I bind jquery's `change()` method to this dynamically added elements ? Right now `change()` is only invoked for static elements.
**EDIT2**
Got the solution. Copy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362880/jquery-can-i-automatically-apply-a-plug-in-to-a-dynamically-added-element).

Comment: Not related to topic but you have declared your variable like this : `needToConfirm = true;` but it's not so healthy. AFAIK, when you declare something like this, you are making this global. put var before that : `var needToConfirm = true;`

Comment: @tugberk: Thanks for the suggestion.I wanted to make it global, I am uisng same variable in other methods also.

Comment: then, I suggest you to bind it to a namespace. A possible collision may happen on client browser if any other browser plugin is using that name. now, it is binded to `window` object. I'm not a JavaScript pro but I know this is not good thing.

Comment: @tugberk: Will bind it to a namespace.Thanks for saving my future efforts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming from the `class="mceEditor"` that you are using the tinyMCE editor.

This will replace the actual element, and so your code will not run on the new element.

Here is the proposed way on handling such a case http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:onchange_callback

---

You basically have to put your change code in a function, and use that when initializing the tinyMCE.

```
 function handleChange() {
        needToConfirm = true;
        alert("needToConfirm :" + needToConfirm); 
    }

 $("select,input,textarea").change(handleChange);
```

and also when you call the tinyMCE initialization add the

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        onchange_callback : handleChange //<-- ADD THIS PART
});
```

Comment: @Ajinkya, updated answer with the official proposal to handle this case.

Comment: How to make a call to `jquery.change` method from `tinyMCE.init` method ?

Comment: @Gaby: I spent many hours to find out the cause. You saved me from putting more efforts :)  Thanks

Comment: @Gaby: All things are working fine but I came across a new issue. I have some HTML elements like `select`,`input` etc which get added dynamically through javascript. How can I bind jquery's `change()` method to this dynamically added elements ? Right now `change()` is only invoked for static elements.

Comment: Ajinkya, you can use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to bind the event. Or if you know that all the elements you want to monitor are container in some common parent, use the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method to bind the event to that.

Comment: @Gaby: Used `.live()` and it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

MCS editor internally using your textarea with `class="mceEditor"`...because of this when you change content of textarea it first call the mceEditor onChange event

Comment: Yes. I removed `class="mceEditor"` and it works. But I cannot remove it from my code. Is there any workaround ?